# Method overloading standard protocol?

Tags: java, overloading

If you add a third signature for a method, do you make the second and third variations directly call the first (the implemented variation), or do you make the third call the second and the second call the first.

It would seem to me that the extra method call would be overhead you could live without, so you'd want all the methods to call the implemented method directly.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any *"standard recommended way"* of doing this or if it's more personal preference or depends on context. I always wonder about it when I add a new signature to an existing overloaded method. You almost always have a choice of which way to do it.

Pathetically Stupid Example:

Existing methods:

```
public String concatenate(String one, String two, String three) {
    return(one+two+three);
}

public String concatenate(String one, String two) {
    return(concatenate(one, two, ""));
}
```

To add the next one, do I do:

```
public String concatenate(String one) {
    return(concatenate(one,"",""));
}
```

OR

```
public String concatenate(String one) {
    return(concatenate(one,""));
}
```

and yes, I am aware that the final method is essentially a no-op.

Comment: Java right? You might want to at the language that you are using to the set of tags.

Comment: Well I didn't think it applied to Java exclusively, seems like a question applicable to any language that supports overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer, when possible, to create a private method that all the other overloaders call.

```
private String _concatenateBase(String one, String two) 
{
    return one + two;
}


public String concatenate(String one, String two, String three) 
{
    return _concatenateBase(one+two, three);
}
```

Comment: This is probably along the lines of how I'd do it, but possibly not private since the base method might be a method that originally was public when you added a new signature. Also, I'm curious as to why you renamed the private method.

Comment: In my mind overloads are a way to express the concept "different inputs to do the same thing". This is mostly useful for the class' Clients: they know what all the concatenate methods do by reading the name. 

But in (my) case where the base method is private (and a little more complex than the example, maybe), I consider it to do a different thing: it implements the behaviour, while the other methods *use* that implementation. 

Of course this is an almost insignificant detail :)

Answer (score 1):

I would *usually* make overloads with fewer arguments call overloads with more arguments, filling in default values. I suspect I'd usually try to avoid duplicating the defaults, so I'd make your third variation call the second, which would call the first. However, it definitely depends on the exact situation. In some cases performance will be a significant factor, although usually readability is much more important. In most cases I doubt that there'll be *very* much difference in readability, particularly if the defaults are simple.

Of course, in some cases overloads aren't structured in this linear way: there may be several overloads which all call the same "core" one, but which couldn't call each other, if they're providing different parameters.